# Negative values for a non-negative parameter in tensorflow probablity

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow-probability

I'm trying to fit a simple Dirichlet-Multinomial model in tensorflow probability. The concentration parameters are `gamma` and I have put a Gamma(1,1) prior distribution on them. This is the model, where S is the number of categories and N is the number of samples:

```
def dirichlet_model(S, N):
    gamma = ed.Gamma(tf.ones(S)*1.0, tf.ones(S)*1.0, name='gamma')
    y = ed.DirichletMultinomial(total_count=500., concentration=gamma, sample_shape=(N), name='y')
    return y

log_joint = ed.make_log_joint_fn(dirichlet_model)
```

However, when I try to sample from this using HMC, the acceptance rate is zero, and the initial draw for `gamma` contains negative values. Am I doing something wrong? Shouldn't negative proposals for the concentration parameters be rejected automatically? Below my sampling code:

```
def target_log_prob_fn(gamma):
  """Unnormalized target density as a function of states."""
  return log_joint(
    S=S, N=N,
    gamma=gamma,
    y=y_new)

num_results = 5000
num_burnin_steps = 3000

states, kernel_results = tfp.mcmc.sample_chain(
  num_results=num_results,
  num_burnin_steps=num_burnin_steps,
  current_state=[
    tf.ones([5], name='init_gamma')*5,
],
kernel=tfp.mcmc.HamiltonianMonteCarlo(
    target_log_prob_fn=target_log_prob_fn,
    step_size=0.4,
    num_leapfrog_steps=3))

gamma = states

with tf.Session() as sess:
  [
    gamma_,
    is_accepted_,
  ] = sess.run([
    gamma,
    kernel_results.is_accepted,
  ])

num_accepted = np.sum(is_accepted_)
print('Acceptance rate: {}'.format(num_accepted / num_results))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try reducing step size to increase acceptance rate. Optimal acceptance rate for HMC is around .651 (https://arxiv.org/abs/1001.4460). Not sure why you'd see negative values. Maybe floating point error near zero? Can you post some of the logs of your run?

Comment: Ah yes, I should have thought of that -- reducing the step size does fix that issue, and the samples are no longer negative. But it would be instructive to know why the initial samples could contain negative values. How do I get the logs?

Comment: Oh by "logs" I just meant whatever you were printing when you saw the negative values. IIRC Gamma is susceptible to numerical stability issues around small parameter values, but without digging deeper I don't have a complete theory for how the negatives could result from this.